# Kotlin Multiplatform freeze object

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I'm new to kotlin multiplatform, and I need to freeze an object as I'm still using the strict memory model. But I cannot solve this dependency on android studio, on my multiplatform module:

`The following reference cannot be resolved: import kotlin.native.concurrent.freeze`

I'm using kotlin 1.6.10 and multiplatform corutines version 1.6.0-native-mt.

Do I have to configure something else to be able to freeze objects on a multiplatform module?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from `kotlin.native.concurrent.freeze` package, and as you can check in [documentation](https://kotlin.native.concurrent.freeze), it's only available on native - you can only use it from `iosMain` or other native platforms.

To use it from common code, you can use [this](https://github.com/touchlab/Stately#stately-common) simple library, or create `expect`/`actual` version of this function by yourself, and just return `this` on Android/JVM:

common:

```
expect fun <T> T.freeze(): T
```

Android/JVM:

```
actual fun <T> T.freeze(): T = this
```

iOS/Native:

```
import kotlin.native.concurrent.freeze

actual fun <T> T.freeze(): T = freeze()
```

Comment: You can also use Stately common, which provides these methods to common code (among other related methods and properties) https://github.com/touchlab/Stately/tree/main/stately-common